# importing javascript app lib does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to import https://github.com/tkurki/dnssd.js and make html file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <h1>DNS-SD Browser</h1>
    <div id="services"></div>
  </section>


  <script>
  const dnssd = require('dnssd2');

  // advertise a http server on port 4321
  const ad = new dnssd2.Advertisement(dnssd.tcp('http'), 4321);
  ad.start();

  // find all chromecasts
  const browser = dnssd2.Browser(dnssd.tcp('_http'))
    .on('serviceUp', service => console.log("Device up: ", service))
    .on('serviceDown', service => console.log("Device down: ", service))
    .start();
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But somehow it shows me error in console log:

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at index.js:1

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at index.js:18

**What am I doing wrong please?**

index.js contains:

```
var Advertisement    = require('./lib/Advertisement');
var Browser          = require('./lib/Browser');
var ServiceType      = require('./lib/ServiceType');
var validate         = require('./lib/validate');
var resolve          = require('./lib/resolve');
var NetworkInterface = require('./lib/NetworkInterface');


module.exports = {
  Advertisement:  Advertisement,
  Browser:        Browser,
  ServiceType:    ServiceType,
  tcp:            ServiceType.tcp,
  udp:            ServiceType.udp,
  all:            ServiceType.all,
  validate:       validate,
  resolve:        resolve.resolve,
  resolveA:       resolve.resolveA,
  resolveAAAA:    resolve.resolveAAAA,
  resolveSRV:     resolve.resolveSRV,
  resolveTXT:     resolve.resolveTXT,
  resolveService: resolve.resolveService,
};
```

Comment: what is there in that index.js ?? can u post the complete code

Comment: require() ist not part of JavaScript. It's a (e. g.) nodejs method.

Comment: @gkrthk, I posted index.js

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't support `require` function

Use [requirejs](https://requirejs.org/). You can also use it with [jquery](https://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html)

You can learn about requirejs from [here](https://requirejs.org/docs/start.html)

Answer (score 0):

Browser doesn't support require out-of-box. try adding this script tag to manually import require from its cdn.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js"></script>
<script src="/index.js"></script>
```